# Give an if statement a variable in Ruby

Tags: ruby, if-statement

I have this if statement:

```
  if value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
    puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x+#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
    puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x"
  elsif value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
   puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x+#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x"
  elsif value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x#{value_n_in_f}"
  end`
```

I have to use this statement really often in other statements and it makes my code unnecessarily long. Obviously if_for_f=if ....... end won't work. Is there any other way? 
Here's an example what I want it to look like:

```
puts "Now we insert #{value_of_x} in #{if_for_f}"
```

Is there any way I can do something like this? Note that I am absolutly new to this.

Thanks in advance,
 Kaiton

Comment: You could write a function called `if_for_f` that takes in any required values.

Comment: It looks to me that the (only) reason the conditions look messy is because the variable names `value_n_in_f` and `value_m_in_f` are long and unusual. If you make them a single letter, that would make it look simple. Actually, your question is not clear.

Comment: Just want to mention that your "Obviously" statement is actually incorrect. You can assign the result of an `if` statement to a variable. Not that you should here, but it is possible - just like J-Dizzle is assigning the result of a `case` statement to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> can't I just def a function with its function to run this case
>   statement and call it then when I need it it?

Of course:

```
def do_stuff(m, n)
  if m == 1
    if n > 0      then "I: f(x)=x+#{n}"
    elsif n == 0  then "I: f(x)=x"
    elsif n < 0   then "I: f(x)=x#{n}"
    end
  else
    if n > 0      then "I: f(x)=#{m}x+#{n}"
    elsif n == 0  then "I: f(x)=#{m}x"
    elsif n < 0   then "I: f(x)=#{m}x#{n}"
    end
  end
end

puts do_stuff(1, 1)  #I: f(x)=x+1
```

Or, if compactness is the goal, we can get to this:

```
def do_stuff(m, n)
  if m == 1
    n == 0  ? "I: f(x)=x"     : "I: f(x)=x#{sprintf("%+d", n)}" 
  else
    n == 0  ? "I: f(x)=#{m}x" : "I: f(x)=#{m}x#{sprintf("%+d", n)}" 
  end
end
```

...and then a one liner:

```
def do_stuff(m, n)
  (m == 1) ? (n == 0  ? "I: f(x)=x" :  "I: f(x)=x#{sprintf("%+d", n)}") : (n == 0  ? "I: f(x)=#{m}x" : "I: f(x)=#{m}x#{sprintf("%+d", n)}")
end
end
```

But your methodology has some problems with zeros and -1:

```
def do_stuff(value_m_in_f, value_n_in_f)
 if value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
    puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x+#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
    puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x"
  elsif value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f != 1
   puts "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x+#{value_n_in_f}"
  elsif value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x"
  elsif value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f == 1
    puts "I: f(x)=x#{value_n_in_f}"
  end
end

do_stuff(1, 0)
do_stuff(1,-1)
do_stuff(1, 1)
do_stuff(0,-1)
do_stuff(0, 0)
do_stuff(-1, 1)

--output:--
I: f(x)=x
I: f(x)=x-1
I: f(x)=x+1
I: f(x)=0x-1   #<---HERE
I: f(x)=0x     #<---HERE
I: f(x)=-1x+1  #<---HERE
```

So let's fix that:

```
def get_line_equ(m, b)
  constant = (b == 0) ? "" : sprintf("%+d", b) # 2 => "+2"

  case m
  when 0 
    xterm = ""
    constant = b
  when 1 
    xterm = "x"
  when -1 
    xterm = "-x"
  else 
    xterm = "#{m}x"
  end

  "I: f(x)=#{xterm}#{constant}"
end

puts get_line_equ(0, 0)
puts get_line_equ(0, -1)
puts get_line_equ(0, 1)

puts get_line_equ(1, 0)
puts get_line_equ(1,-1)
puts get_line_equ(1, 1)

puts get_line_equ(-1, 0)
puts get_line_equ(-1, -1)
puts get_line_equ(-1, 1)

puts get_line_equ(2, 0)
puts get_line_equ(2, -1)
puts get_line_equ(2, 1)

--output:--
I: f(x)=0
I: f(x)=-1
I: f(x)=1
I: f(x)=x
I: f(x)=x-1
I: f(x)=x+1
I: f(x)=-x
I: f(x)=-x-1
I: f(x)=-x+1
I: f(x)=2x
I: f(x)=2x-1
I: f(x)=2x+1
```

Better?

spoiler:

> The final def is not as efficient as it could be: the first line should be removed and copied to each of the when branches--except for the first.

In response to comment:

```
def my_sprintf(str, *numbers)
  str.gsub(/% .*? [df]/x) do |match|  #Looks for %...d or %...f sequences
    puts match
  end
end

my_sprintf("The answer is: %+d or %+d", -2, 3)


--output:--
%+d
%+d
```

Next:

```
def my_sprintf(str, *numbers)

  str.gsub(/% .*? [df]/x) do |format_sequ|
    number_as_str = numbers.shift.to_s
    p number_as_str

    if format_sequ[1] == "+" and number_as_str[0] != "-"
      "+#{number_as_str}"
    else
      number_as_str
    end

  end
end

puts my_sprintf("The answer is: %+d or %+d.", -2, 3)

--output:--
"-2"
"3"
The answer is: -2 or +3.
```

Comment: Thank you, but what is sprintf?

Comment: Okay, I think I understood sprintf now. I have a problem though, I want fractions, but when I call sprintf{"%+f", 1.5} I get => 1.50000000, how can I get it to act like an usual fraction, only displaying the digits I give him? And secondly. Can someone explain, why the plus in "%+d" doesn't show up when giving a negativ n? I mean it's super useful, but I don't understand why it does that.

Comment: @Kaiton, **Can someone explain, why the plus in "%+d" doesn't show up when giving a negativ n?** sprintf() is a method, and as such it can be programmed to do whatever it wants.  And that's the way it was programmed to work. Or is it that you can't understand how a computer program can do one thing in one situation and another thing in another situation?  See the bottom of my answer for a simple implementation of sprintf().

Comment: @Kaiton, **I have a problem though, I want fractions** In your opinion, what is a fraction? Post an example of a fraction.  Instead of trying to describe the output you want, why don't you just post the output you want?

Comment: Thank you for your help so far. What I mean by fraction is that if I input 'print get_f(value_m_in_f, 2)' (with value_m_in_f=STDIN.gets.to_f <=1.5), I want to have this output: "I: f(x)=1.5x+2", but I get "I: f(x)=1.5000000x+2" instead".

Comment: Here an example: This is my output with get_f(4.0, 2.0): http://puu.sh/bp81s/12941fff29.png

Comment: @Kaiton, fyi a fraction looks like this: 3/4, 1/2, 2/3. Secondly, what's the point in converting a string to a float, and then converting it to a string again inside the method? Why not just do `m = gets` and pass strings to the method?

Answer (score 4):

Here's a more compact way to write your case statement. Recall that `a <=> b => -1 if a < b`, `a <=> b => 0 if a == b` and `a <=> b => -1 if a > b`.

```
"I: f(x)=" +
case [value_n_in_f <=> 0, value_m_in_f == 1]
when [ 1,false] then "#{value_m_in_f}x+#{value_n_in_f}"
when [ 0,false] then "#{value_m_in_f}x"
when [-1,false] then "#{value_m_in_f}x#{value_n_in_f}"
when [ 1,true]  then "x+#{value_n_in_f}"
when [ 0,true]  then "x"
when [-1,true]  then "x#{value_n_in_f}"
end
```

If you wish to demonstrate how the string is built, you could do something like this (with `value_n_in_f` and `value_m_in_f` renamed `intercept` and `slope`, respectively):

```
"I: f(x)=" +
case
when slope.zero?
  intercept.zero? ? "0" : "#{intercept}"
else
  case slope.to_f
  when  1.0 then ""
  when -1.0 then "-"
  else "#{slope}"
  end + "x" +
  case intercept <=> 0
  when  0 then ""
  when -1 then "#{intercept}"
  else "+#{intercept}"    
  end
end
```

Note that this permits `slope < 0`, which is not part of the specification. I tested this for various combinations of `intercept` and `slope`:

```
   intercept slope    string
       -2.1   4      I: f(x)=4x-2.1
       -2.1   -2.2   I: f(x)=-2.2x-2.1
       -2.1   0      I: f(x)=-2.1
       -2.1   0.0    I: f(x)=-2.1
       -2.1   -1     I: f(x)=-x-2.1
       -2.1   1.0    I: f(x)=x-2.1
       0      4      I: f(x)=4x
       0      -2.2   I: f(x)=-2.2x
       0      0      I: f(x)=0
       0      0.0    I: f(x)=0
       0      -1     I: f(x)=-x
       0      1.0    I: f(x)=x
       0.0    4      I: f(x)=4x
       0.0    -2.2   I: f(x)=-2.2x
       0.0    0      I: f(x)=0
       0.0    0.0    I: f(x)=0
       0.0    -1     I: f(x)=-x
       0.0    1.0    I: f(x)=x
       3      4      I: f(x)=4x+3
       3      -2.2   I: f(x)=-2.2x+3
       3      0      I: f(x)=3
       3      0.0    I: f(x)=3
       3      -1     I: f(x)=-x+3
       3      1.0    I: f(x)=x+3
```

Answer (score 2):

A couple of things here: you can put "puts" before the whole if/elsif block and avoid having puts on every line, like so:

```
puts case 
  when (value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f != 1) then "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x+#{value_n_in_f}"
  when (value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f != 1) then "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x"
end
```

Second, a case statement would be much more readable, like so:

```
def big_compare(value_n_in_f, value_m_in_f)
  msg = case
    when (value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f != 1) then "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x+#{value_n_in_f}"
    when (value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f != 1) then "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x"
    when (value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f != 1) then "I: f(x)=#{value_m_in_f}x#{value_n_in_f}"
    when (value_n_in_f > 0 && value_m_in_f == 1) then "I: f(x)=x+#{value_n_in_f}"
    when (value_n_in_f == 0 && value_m_in_f == 1) then "I: f(x)=x"
    when (value_n_in_f < 0 && value_m_in_f == 1) then "I: f(x)=x#{value_n_in_f}"
  end
end
puts big_compare(0, 0)
```

Comment: I see, that's very usefull. Thank you. So, that means there is no way to assign a case/if statement to a variable, like you do with a function? can't I just def a function with its function to run this case statement and call it then when I need it it?